# How can I parse my json string so that I can show only values?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a json file that comes from my php script:

```
[{"client_name":"Rob","contact_name":"contact","addr_line1":"line1"}
```

and now I want to put the values to variables.
I did the ajax call for them:

```
                    $.ajax({
                        url: './getJson.php', 
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            email: email
                        },
                        dataType:'text',
                        success: function(response)
                        {

                            client_data = JSON.parse(response);
                            alert(client_data.client_name); // it alerts 'undefined'


                        }
                    });
```

How can I avoid printing out undefined and see the real data from my script?

Comment: data looks like it is an array  not an object ... but is also invalid structure without matching braces. If you are only expecting one client fix server output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data is an array containing an object with a client_name property.

You are trying to treat it as an object with a client_name property while ignoring the array altogether.

Use `[0]` to access the first member of the array. Consider using a loop instead.

Comment: but when I'm doing `alert(client_data[0])` it returns me `[Object object]`.. How can I display the name instead?

Comment: With `.client_name`! You still need to access the object property. It's good paying attention to the array and forgetting the object exists!

Comment: `alert(client_data.client_name[0]);` shows me the error in the console that says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` - is that what you suggested?

Comment: The array contains the object, not the other way around.